# How to generate Java client for Jira WADL?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jira, wadl

all

I tried to generate Java client from Jira wadl descriptor, but it does not work:
 **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Single WADL resources element is expected**

WADL file used: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/7.0.4/jira-rest-plugin.wadl

Build used:

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-wadl2java-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wadlOptions>
                                <wadlOption>
                                    <wadl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jira-rest-plugin.wadl</wadl>
                                    <impl>true</impl>

                                    <packagename>com.mycompany.jira</packagename>
                                    <schemaPackagenames>
                                       <schemaPackagename>http://mycompany=com.mycompany.jira.schema</schemaPackagename>
                                    </schemaPackagenames>

                                </wadlOption>
                            </wadlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wadl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I had a hope that they fixed their WADL in 7.x ...

Anybody who made it work?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like valid `WADL` file, it explains individual services, with input, input format. For a wadl2java plugin to work you need to have WADL file with syntax similar to shown below.

```
<application xmlns="http://research.sun.com/wadl/2006/10">
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.dev.java.net/" 
            jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 1.0-ea-SNAPSHOT 10/02/2008 12:17 PM"/>
    <resources base="http://localhost:9998/storage/">
        <resource path="/containers">
            <method name="GET" id="getContainers">
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                </response>
            </method>
            <!-- Next methods ->
        </resource>
     </resources>
  </application>
```

I guess only way for you is to contact `atlassian` to provide at valid WADL file if the support, else you might need to use top down approach and implement the syntax as shown in the link you shared

Comment: According to their official documentation THIS IS their WADL file. See here: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/7.0.4/#JIRA4.2RESTAPIdiscussionpoints-StructureoftheRESTURIs

Comment: In the link you provide There is a WADL document that contains the documentation for each resource in the JIRA REST API. It is available here. The link here points to https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/7.0.4/jira-rest-plugin.wadl, which does not adheere to WADL syntax.

Comment: Summarizing: the so called 'WADL document' they provided (https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/7.0.4/jira-rest-plugin.wadl) on their documentation page (https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/7.0.4/#JIRA4.2RESTAPIdiscussionpoints-StructureoftheRESTURIs) does not adhere to WADL standard.
It may exist somewhere else but you need to request it.
Do you need to have some kind of extra support/license contract to get that?

Comment: Yes. Exactly, I don't think that would need extra license. Certainly you can ask them

Answer (score 0):

Here is some additional info,
1) go to your specific server version api docs url.
eg:- https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.12.3/

2) Append "jira-rest-plugin.wadl" to the end and press enter
This downloads the wadl for the specific version you want

3) Signup for free in Apimatic.io and login

4) Use the transformer to upload the wadl and specify the output format (Swagger openapi v2.0 or 3.0, or postman, etc.)

5) THis will generate and download the swagger.json